# How to call a method with parameter IDataReader in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

**I am calling a codebehind method from Javascript and passing that value in hiddenfields, From that method I need to call an another method which has an parameter IdataReader how to do  ?**

```
   page1.aspx  
   function changeCurrencyinternaluser()
        {
            curhf=document.getElementById('TableBuilder1_hf_currency');
            currencylit=document.getElementById('lit_currency');
            if (currencylit && curhf) 
                currencylit.innerHTML=curhf.value;                      
                curhfid=document.getElementById('TableBuilder1_hf_currencyid');
                currencyid=curhfid.value; 

                 document.getElementById('<%= h3plcurrid.ClientID %>').value = currencyid;   //deep
                 document.getElementById('<%= LinkButton2.ClientID %>').click();              
        }


   page1.aspx.cs
     protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        usercurrid = h3plcurrid.Value;  // hidden field
       //I need to call below method getsupplierNumber 

     }


    private Control getSupplierNumber(IDataReader dr)
     {
      //some code
     }
```

Comment: -1 [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: The above javascript function is called from anotherpage and on the 1st page ,I do get a value but the o/p page need to be modified accoeding to value I am getting from 2nd page ,so I have taken a hidden field and on its click event I have called a method(its codebehind page) but from that method I need to call another method where logic is written to modify the result but the problem is the method has an parameter IdataReader.

Answer (score 1):

A typical usage would be: to execute a SQL command, for example:

```
using(var conn = GetAnOpenConnection())
using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = ...
    cmd.Parameters.Add(...);
    using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var control = getSupplierNumber(reader);
    }
}
```

However, while `IDataReader` *usually* relates to a database, it is not required to do so. You can write custom `IDataReader` implementations pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

pass one more value check this way usercurrid also while (CarsInfoDataReader.Read())
{if (usercurrid==CarsInfoDataReader[index].tostring())  {
  ///if satisfies fill the values show it to the user  }

}